# ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Tags: android, kotlin, crop

I am experiencing one weird thing while using ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper,
everything works fine, the image is sent to crop activity and cropped image is retrieved to ImageView.
However, when I press crop button to launch Crop Activity the original image is saved in the gallery by itself. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
   mBinding.btnCrop.setOnClickListener {
        filteredBM.value?.let {


            val uri = getImageUri(this, it)
            imageUri = uri

         CropImage.activity(imageUri)
             .start(this)





        }


    }
```

So the image is already in the image view when launching crop activity. In onActivityResult I put the cropped image into that image view and everything works fine except for that original image being saved in the gallery.

Comment: Found: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/858

Comment: Can use the new library https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper